# Secondary disk safe to use after potential virus?

Tags: malware, hardware, windows-10

I've recently bought a new disk and made a fresh install on a home PC after having potential malware (or a very corrupted registry, whatever your take is on having numerous Blue Screens of Death, one after the other.)

Before the fresh install on the new disk, I unplugged the two disks I had (two SSDs, a C: and D: drive). I have installed anti-virus software (Norton) and the latest system updates. My question is, could my secondary SSD be infected with the same malware from the old C: drive?

Related - [Could once infected machine be ever trusted again?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32123/could-once-infected-machine-be-ever-trusted-again?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is, could my secondary SSD be infected with the same malware from the old C: drive?

Yes.  Either trust your antivirus to do it's job after reinstall, wipe the disk or destroy the disk.

If there are important files, plug the drive into an inert machine and copy the minimum amount of files after verifying they have not been modified.

What computers are "inert" is an almost impossible question to answer.  If a virus is tailored to Windows, Linux is fine.  If the virus is somehow carrying a payload for Windows, Linux and Mac; IDK BSD, solaris, gnu hurd, Haiku.